# Can I download the disco version of NBA 2K 18 on my cousins PlayStation and then go home and read download it on mine?

Tags: playstation-plus, nba2k18

I got a new game for Christmas, Nba2k18 and I don’t live in Italy which is where I got it I live in Sweden but I want to play it soon so I asked my cousin if we could play together at his house with his PlayStation. Can I put the game in his PlayStation as the first but still go home and play it on mine as well, obviously when I put it in is his console it’ll be under my account.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a disc version you can play it on any one console at a time (the one the disc is currently inserted). Otherwise disc resale would be impossible. You can bring it to your cousin's house insert the disc and play, then bring the disc back home and play on your own PS4 with no problems.

Downloading the game is not necessary, just something the PS4 does on it's own to decrease load times mostly. This doesn't attach the disc to any specific console or account.

Comment: There may be an issue with Region, but yes, as the poster stated, you can swap games between consoles. But only the console with the disc can play the game.